# Switch case program keeps looping at a certain point. Cant figure out

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I think i done about everything I can but it when i press options pass 3, it always shows up as option 3. Case 1,2,3 work as intended but 4,5,6,7,8,9,10 will just automatically should up as case 3. So what do you think is missing?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int pgk, ch1, ch2; // variables for the Menu1 and Menu2
char ch3; // Variable for menu 3


int main()
{
        printf("1, Final Lab\n"); // first option
        printf("2, Exit\n");// second option
        cin >> ch1; // computer is going to scan the option from keyboard
        // Switch change the option depending of the number we put in the keyboard
        switch (ch1)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            goto Menu2; // if the user enters 1, it is going to send to send it to do the operations
        }
        case 2:
        {
            goto End; // if the user enters 2, it is going to end the program.
        }

    Menu2:
        printf(" --------------------------Menu-------------------\n");
        printf("1:Pounds to kilograms\n");
        printf("2:inches to centimeters\n"); 
        printf("3:cups to milliters\n"); 
        printf("4:seconds to minutes \n"); 
        printf("5:Knots to mph\n"); 
        printf("6:tip calculator\n"); 
        printf("7:Grade average\n"); 
        printf("8:target heart rate calculator\n");
        printf("9:discount calculator\n");
        printf("10:end\n"); 
        cin >> ch2; // enter the option the user wants
        switch (ch2) // Options
        {
        case 1: 
        {
            system("cls");
            int pkg;
            printf("Choose to convert pounds to kg or kg to pounds. Press 0 for 1st option and press any other number for 2nd option.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &pkg);
            _asm
            {
                MOV EBX, pkg;
                CMP pkg, 0;
                JE pounds_kilos;
                JMP kilos_pounds;
            }

        pounds_kilos:
            float nguypounds, nguyconvert1, nguyanswer1;
            nguyconvert1 = 2.204622f;
            printf("Enter the amount of pounds you would like to convert to kilograms\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguypounds);

            _asm
            {

                FLD nguypounds;
                FDIV nguyconvert1;
                FST nguyanswer1;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of pounds to kilograms is %f\n", nguyanswer1);
            system("pause");
            goto Menu3;

        kilos_pounds:
            float nguykilos, nguyconvert2, nguyanswer2;
            nguyconvert2 = 2.204622f;
            printf("Enter the amount of kilograms you would like to convert to pounds\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguykilos);

            _asm
            {
                FLD nguykilos;
                FMUL nguyconvert2;
                FST nguyanswer2;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of kilograms to pounds is %f\n", nguyanswer2);
            goto Menu3;

        }

        case 2: // if the user enters 2
        {

            system("cls");
            int pkg;
            printf("Choose to convert inches to centimeters or centimeters to inches. Press 0 for 1st option and press any other number for 2nd option.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &pkg);
            _asm
            {
                MOV EBX, pkg;
                CMP pkg, 0;
                JE inches_centimeters;
                JMP centimeters_inches;
            }

        inches_centimeters:
            float nguyinches, nguyconvert3, nguyanswer3;
            nguyconvert3 = 2.54f;
            printf("Enter the amount of inches you would like to convert to centimeters\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguyinches);

            _asm
            {

                FLD nguyinches;
                FMUL nguyconvert3;
                FST nguyanswer3;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of inches to centimeters is %f\n", nguyanswer3);
            goto Menu3;
        }
        centimeters_inches:
            float nguycentimeters, nguyconvert4, nguyanswer4;
            nguyconvert4 = 0.39370079f;
            printf("Enter the amount of centimeters you like to convert to inches\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguycentimeters);

            _asm
            {
                FLD nguycentimeters;
                FMUL nguyconvert4;
                FST nguyanswer4;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of centimeters to inches is %f\n", nguyanswer4);

            goto Menu3;

        }
        case 3: // if the user enter 3 
        {
            system("cls");
            int pkg;
            printf("Choose to convert cups to milliters or milliters to cups. Press 0 for 1st option and press any other number for 2nd option.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &pkg);
            _asm
            {
                MOV EBX, pkg;
                CMP pkg, 0;
                JE cups_milliters;
                JMP milliters_cups;
            }

        cups_milliters:
            float nguycups, nguyconvert5, nguyanswer5;
            nguyconvert5 = 236.58823f;
            printf("Enter the amount of cups you would like to convert to milliters\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguycups);

            _asm
            {

                FLD nguycups;
                FMUL nguyconvert5;
                FST nguyanswer5;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of cups to milliters is %f\n", nguyanswer5);
            system("pause");

            goto Menu3;

        milliters_cups:
            float nguymilliters, nguyconvert6, nguyanswer6;
            nguyconvert6 = 236.58823f;
            printf("Enter the amount of milliters you like to convert to cups\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguymilliters);

            _asm
            {
                FLD nguymilliters;
                FDIV nguyconvert6;
                FST nguyanswer6;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of milliters to cups is %f\n", nguyanswer6);
            goto Menu3;

        }
        case 4: // if the user enters 4
        {
            system("cls");
            int pkg;
            printf("Choose to convert seconds to minutes or minutes to seconds. Press 0 for 1st option and press any other number for 2nd option.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &pkg);
            _asm
            {
                MOV EBX, pkg;
                CMP pkg, 0;
                JE sec_min;
                JMP min_sec;
            }
        sec_min:
            float nguyseconds, nguyconvert7, nguyanswer7;
            nguyconvert7 = 60;
            printf("Enter the amount of seconds you would like to convert to minutes\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguyseconds);

            _asm
            {

                FLD nguyseconds;
                FDIV nguyconvert7;
                FST nguyanswer7;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of seconds to minutes is %f\n", nguyanswer7);
            goto Menu3;

        min_sec:
            float nguyminutes, nguyconvert8, nguyanswer8;
            nguyconvert8 = 60;
            printf("Enter the amount of minutes you like to convert to seconds\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguyminutes);

            _asm
            {
                FLD nguyminutes;
                FMUL nguyconvert8;
                FST nguyanswer8;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of minutes to seconds is %f\n", nguyanswer8);
            system("pause");
            goto Menu3;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            system("cls");
            int pkg;
            printf("Choose to knots to mph or mph to knots. P=ress 0 for 1st option and press any other number for 2nd option.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &pkg);
            _asm
            {
                MOV EBX, pkg;
                CMP pkg, 0;
                JE knots_mph;
                JMP mph_knots;
            }
        knots_mph:
            float nguyknots, nguyconvert9, nguyanswer9;
            nguyconvert9 = 1.15f;
            printf("Enter the amount of knots you would like to convert to mph\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguyknots);

            _asm
            {

                FLD nguyknots;
                FMUL nguyconvert9;
                FST nguyanswer9;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of knots to mph is %f\n", nguyanswer9);
            goto Menu3;

        mph_knots:
            float nguymph, nguyconvert10, nguyanswer10;
            nguyconvert10 = 1.15f;
            printf("Enter the amount of mph you like to convert to knots\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguymph);

            _asm
            {
                FLD nguymph;
                FDIV nguyconvert10;
                FST nguyanswer10;
            }
            printf("Your enter number of minutes to seconds is %f\n", nguyanswer10);
            system("pause");
            goto Menu3;

        }
        case 6:
        {
            system("cls");
            float nguybill, nguytip, nguyamount;
            printf("Please enter the total amount of your bill\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguybill);
            printf("Now add the percentage you would like to tip. PLEASE ENTER IN PERCENTAGE IN DECIMAL FORM!\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguytip);

            _asm
            {
                fld nguybill
                    fld nguytip
                    fmul nguybill
                    fadd st(0), st(1)
                    fst nguyamount
            }
            printf("the the toal amount after tip is %f\n", nguyamount);
            goto Menu3;

        }
        case 7:
        {
            system("cls");
            float nguytest1, nguytest2, nguytest3, nguyave, nguytotave;
            nguyave = 3;
            printf("Please enter the grade of your first test.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguytest1);
            printf("Please enter the grade of your second test.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguytest2);
            printf("Please enter the grade of your thrid test.\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguytest3);
            _asm
            {
                fld nguytest1
                    fld nguytest2
                    fld nguytest3
                    fadd st(0), st(1)
                    fadd st(0), st(2)
                    fdiv nguyave
                    fst nguytotave
            }
            printf("Your average grade is %f", nguytotave);
            goto Menu3;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            system("cls");
            float nguyage, nguyageconst, nguymaxhr, nguytarghr, nguymulmax;
            nguyageconst = 220;
            nguymulmax = .70f;
            printf("Please enter the total amount of your age to find your max heart rate and target heart rate\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguyage);

            _asm
            {
                fld nguyage
                    fld nguyageconst
                    fsub nguyage
                    fst nguymaxhr
            }

            _asm
            {
                fld nguymaxhr
                    fmul nguymulmax
                    fst nguytarghr
            }
            printf("your max heart rate should be %f beat per minute\n", nguymaxhr);
            printf("and your target heart rate should be %f beats per minute\n", nguytarghr);
            goto Menu3;

        }
        case 9:
        {
            system("cls");
            float nguyogprice, nguydis, nguyoff, nguynamount;
            printf("Please enter the oringal price\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguyogprice);
            printf("Now enter the given discout. PLEASE ENTER IN PERCENTAGE IN DECIMAL FORM!\n");
            scanf_s("%f", &nguydis);

            _asm
            {
                fld nguyogprice
                    fld nguydis
                    fmul nguyogprice
                    fst nguyoff
            }

            _asm
            {
                fld nguyoff
                    fld nguyogprice
                    fsub st(0), st(1)
                    fst nguynamount
            }
            printf("The new sale price is %f\n", nguynamount);
            goto Menu3;

        }
        case 10: // if the user enters 5
        {
            goto End; //go to end
        }
        }

    Menu3: // This menu is going to ask if the user wants to continue the program
        printf(" -------------------------Question---------------------\n"); // display message 
        printf("Do you want to continue the program Y/N\n"); // display message
        cin >> ch3; // enter yes or no
        switch (ch3) // conditional 
        {
        case 'y': // if the user enters 'y'
        {
            goto Menu2; // go to menu 2 and continue the program 
        }
        case 'Y': // if the user enters 'Y'
        {
            goto Menu2; // go to menu 2 and continue the program
        }
        case 'n': // if the user enters 'n'
        {
            goto End; // finish the program
        }
        case 'N': // if the user enters 'N'
        {
            goto End; // finish the program
        }


        }

    End: // menu to end the program
        system("pause"); // pause the system
        return 0;// end program

    }
```

Comment: Why are there all the assembly blocks instead of normal math operations?

Answer (score 6):

The closing curly brace just before `case 3` is placed there erroneously, it closes the switch statement. Thus inputs 3 through 9 all end up in case 3.

No offence intended, but use of goto outside very specific contexts has since long been branded as extremely bad programming practice for reasons of poor maintainability and efficiency (optimizing opportunities for the compiler). Investing time and effort to disentangle the code and restructuring of the program will pay off.